# jQuery Autocomplete City & Country based on zip code

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, postal

I was wondering if anyone knew a good service for City and Country Lookup by postal code, I was using the `ziptasic plugin` from `jQuery`, but it only supports the US and I need to search within Canada, both would be great. I know `google maps API` is another method but I dont even know where to start.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Please can anyone help!? I am desperate here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the ziptastic plugin Version 2, and the golocation jquery plugin!

Thanks for the insight tho!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.maxmind.com/app/postalcode